# Find all triples $(p, q, r)$ of primes such that $p - 2q + r = 1$ and $p^3 - 2q^3 + (4r)^3 = 2023$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

**Problem**

> Find all triples $(p, q, r)$ of primes such that
> $p - 2q + r = 1$ and $p^3 - 2q^3 + (4r)^3 = 2023$.

This problem is from the algebra round of a local high school competition that has already ended.

**Almost Solved! (With help from dxiv and insipidintegrator)**

We can rearrange the first equation as $p + r = 2q + 1$. Since $2q + 1$ is always odd, either $p$ or $r$ must be even. The only even prime number is $2$.

Case 1: $p = 2$

If $p = 2$, then the equation $p + r = 2q + 1$ becomes $r = 2q - 1$. Substituting this value of r into the second equation, we have:

$8 - 2q^3 + 64(2q - 1)^3 = 2023$.

This equation does not work because the sum of two even numbers can not equal an odd number. Therefore, case 1 does not work.

Case 2: $r = 2$

If $r = 2$, then the equation $p + r = 2q + 1$ becomes $p = 2q - 1$. Substituting this value of $p$ into the second equation, we have:

$(2q - 1)^3 - 2q^3 + (4(2))^3 = 2023$.

Expanding and simplifying:

$6q^3 - 12q^2 + 6q - 1 + 512 = 2023$,
$6q^3 - 12q^2 + 6q = 1512$.

Dividing by 6, we get:

$q^3 - 2q^2 + q - 252 = 0$.

It would take so long if I try to use rational root theorem to solve this.

Is there any better way to solve this cubic? Also, has all my steps been correct so far? Thank you!

Comment: You can't have an even number $=2023$.

Comment: @dxiv Yeah, I am so confused :(

Comment: This means *Case 1* is not possible. So, try the other case and see what you get.

Comment: @JHumpdos this basically means that the case p=2 is not feasible and must be thus discarded. Now try with r=2 and then solve the problem.

Comment: Ok! Thank you, I will try that!

Comment: You already know that $q$ is prime, so from
$$q^3-2q^2+q-252=0,$$
you know that $q$ is a prime factor of $252=2^2\times3^2\times7$, so you just need to try $q=2,3,7$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The $2$ simultaneous equations to solve are:

$$p-2q+r=1,\;\;p^3-2q^3+(4r)^3=2023 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Since $2023$ is odd, the second equation shows $p$ must be odd. The first equation then shows that $r$ must be even, i.e., it's $2$ as that's the only even prime. Thus, $p = 2q - 1$ from the first equation in \eqref{eq1A} which, when substituted in the second one, gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
(2q-1)^3-2q^3+8^3 &= 2023 \\
(8q^3 - 12q^2 + 6q - 1) - 2q^3 + 512 & = 2023 \\
6q^3 - 12q^2 + 6q - 1512 & = 0 \\
q^3 - 2q^2 + q - 252 & = 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

As we're looking only for primes $q$, note the first prime where its cube is about $252$ is $7$ (with $7^3 = 343$ being somewhat larger). Alternatively, we can relatively quickly determine $9$ divides $252$ since $2+5+2=9$, and it also has a factor of $4$ (since $4 \mid 52$ and $4 \mid 200$), so factoring gives $252 = 4(9)(7)$. The [Rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) (RRT) then indicates $7$ is a possible factor.

Since $q = 7$ satisfies \eqref{eq2A}, then $q - 7$ can be factored out to get the remaining factor of $q^2 + 5q + 36$. However, the discriminant of this quadratic polynomial is $\Delta = 5^2 - 4(36) = -119 \lt 0$, so it has no real factors (also, the RRT indicates the only other possible prime factors $q$ of \eqref{eq2A} are $2$ and $3$, but neither satisfy the equation). Thus, the only solution is

$$(r,p,q) = (2,13,7) \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Comment: ooh! this is a great way to solve the cubic!!

Answer (score 2):

First, let's do the arithmetic modulo 2, i.e., just consider whether the variables are odd or even.

- $p - 2q + r = 1$ is equivalent to $p + r = 1$.  In other words, one of $(p, r)$ is even, and the other is odd.
- $p^3 - 2q^3 + (4r)^3 = 2023$ is equivalent to $p^3 = 1$.  IOW, $p^3$ is odd, which means that $p$ is odd.

So, $p$ must be odd, and $r$ must be even.  But there's only one even prime number, so we must have $\boxed{r = 2}$.  Let's make this substitution to simplify solving for $p$ and $q$.

$$p - 2q = -1$$
$$p^3 - 2q^3 = 1511$$

From the former equation, we have $p = 2q - 1$.  Substituting into the second equation gives:

$$(2q - 1)^3 - 2q^3 = 1511$$
$$(2q)^3 + 3(2q)^2(-1) + 3(2q)(-1)^2 + (-1)^3 - 2q^3 = 1511$$
$$8q^3 - 12q^2 + 6q - 1 - 2q^3 = 1511$$
$$6q^3 - 12q^2 + 6q - 1512 = 0$$
$$q^3 - 2q^2 + q - 252 = 0$$

By the Rational Root Theorem, any rational roots must be factors of 252, i.e.,

$$|q| \in \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 12, 14, 18, 21, 28, 36, 42, 63, 84, 126, 252 \}$$

However, the problem requires that $q$ be a *prime* number, so this reduces the relevant solutions to:

$$q \in \{ 2, 3, 7 \}$$

Trying all of these, we find that $q = 7$ works.  We need not bother finding the other two roots of the cubic, because aren't in the valid solution set $\{ 2, 3, 7 \}$.  But if you insist on finding them anyway, factoring out $q - 7$ from the cubic gives $q^2 + 5q + 36 = 0$, from which the quadratic formula gives $q = \frac{-5 \pm i\sqrt{119}}{2}$.  These aren't even *real*, let alone prime, so they don't count.

Finally, plugging $q = 7$ into the previously-established $p = 2q-1$ gives $p = 13$.  This satisfies the previously-established facts that $p$ is prime (given) and $p$ is odd (from the modulo-2 equations above), so is a valid solution.

Therefore, $\boxed{p = 13, q = 7, r = 2}$ is the unique solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You got as far as
$$q^3-2q^2+q-252=0$$
Rearranging,
$$q(q-1)^2=252=4\times 7\times 9$$
And now it's clear that $q=7$ is the only solution, because $q=5$ is too small and $q=11$ is too big (and neither of them is a factor of $252$ anyway).

Comment: (+1). Or since $q$ is prime, we have $7\mid q\implies q=7$ or $7\mid q-1$. If $q=7k+1$, then $49\mid \rm RHS$ . A contradiction. Thus $q=7$.